# Linux HID driver for keyboards sending 1 extra byte

Tags: linux, drivers, usb, keyboard, hid

I bought a new keyboard similar to an old one. The old one works, the new one not. There is a difference in one extra data byte sent by the new keyboard. Is there a Linux driver which support the new one?

---

Communication log via `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/3u`, byte sequences only (press 'A', release 'A'. press 'S', release 'S'. press 'Shift', press 'A', release 'A', release 'Shift' sequence):

Non-working 9-byte keyboard communication:

```
00000400 00000000 71
00000000 00000000 71
00001600 00000000 71
00000000 00000000 71
02000000 00000000 71
02000400 00000000 71
02000000 00000000 71
00000000 00000000 71
```

Working old keyboard communication:

```
00000400 00000000
00000000 00000000
00001600 00000000
00000000 00000000
02000000 00000000
02000400 00000000
02000000 00000000
00000000 00000000
```

Bonus: What is the extra byte? (I always saw `0x71` there.)

---

HID Descriptors of the new keyboard via `cat /sys/kernel/debug/hid/<interface>/rdesc`:

Interface `0003:17EF:609B.0089`:

```
05 01 09 06 a1 01 05 07 19 e0 29 e7 15 00 25 01 75 01 95 08 81 02 75 08 95 01 81 01 05 08 19 01 29 03 75 01 95 03 91 02 95 01 75 05 91 01 15 00 26 ff 00 19 00 2a ff 00 05 07 75 08 95 06 81 00 05 01 0a 68 01 15 80 25 7f 95 01 75 08 81 02 c0 

  INPUT[INPUT]
    Field(0)
      Application(GenericDesktop.Keyboard)
      Usage(8)
        Keyboard.00e0
        Keyboard.00e1
        Keyboard.00e2
        Keyboard.00e3
        Keyboard.00e4
        Keyboard.00e5
        Keyboard.00e6
        Keyboard.00e7
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(1)
      Report Size(1)
      Report Count(8)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Variable Absolute )
    Field(1)
      Application(GenericDesktop.Keyboard)
      Usage(256)
        LED.0000
        LED.NumLock
        LED.CapsLock
        LED.ScrollLock
        LED.Compose
        LED.Kana
        LED.0006
        LED.0007
        LED.0008
        LED.0009
        ... LED sequence left out
        LED.0049
        LED.004a
        LED.GenericIndicator
        LED.004c
        LED.004d
        LED.004e
        LED.004f
        ... LED sequence left out
        LED.00fd
        LED.00fe
        LED.00ff
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(255)
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(6)
      Report Offset(16)
      Flags( Array Absolute )
    Field(2)
      Application(GenericDesktop.Keyboard)
      Usage(1)
        GenericDesktop.0168
      Logical Minimum(-128)
      Logical Maximum(127)
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(64)
      Flags( Variable Absolute )
  OUTPUT[OUTPUT]
    Field(0)
      Application(GenericDesktop.Keyboard)
      Usage(3)
        LED.NumLock
        LED.CapsLock
        LED.ScrollLock
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(1)
      Report Size(1)
      Report Count(3)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Variable Absolute )

Keyboard.00e0 ---> Key.LeftControl
Keyboard.00e1 ---> Key.LeftShift
Keyboard.00e2 ---> Key.LeftAlt
Keyboard.00e3 ---> Key.LeftMeta
Keyboard.00e4 ---> Key.RightCtrl
Keyboard.00e5 ---> Key.RightShift
Keyboard.00e6 ---> Key.RightAlt
Keyboard.00e7 ---> Key.RightMeta
LED.0000 ---> Sync.Report
LED.NumLock ---> LED.NumLock
LED.CapsLock ---> LED.CapsLock
LED.ScrollLock ---> LED.ScrollLock
LED.Compose ---> LED.Compose
LED.Kana ---> LED.Kana
LED.0006 ---> Sync.Report
LED.0007 ---> Sync.Report
LED.0008 ---> Sync.Report
LED.0009 ---> LED.Mute
LED.000a ---> Sync.Report
LED.000b ---> Sync.Report
... Sync.Report lines left out
LED.0017 ---> Sync.Report
LED.0018 ---> Sync.Report
LED.0019 ---> LED.?
LED.001a ---> Sync.Report
LED.001b ---> Sync.Report
... Sync.Report lines left out
LED.0025 ---> Sync.Report
LED.0026 ---> Sync.Report
LED.0027 ---> LED.Sleep
LED.0028 ---> Sync.Report
LED.0029 ---> Sync.Report
... Sync.Report lines left out
LED.0049 ---> Sync.Report
LED.004a ---> Sync.Report
LED.GenericIndicator ---> LED.Misc
LED.004c ---> LED.Suspend
LED.004d ---> LED.?
LED.004e ---> Sync.Report
LED.004f ---> Sync.Report
... Sync.Report lines left out
LED.00fe ---> Sync.Report
LED.00ff ---> Sync.Report
GenericDesktop.0168 ---> Absolute.Misc
LED.NumLock ---> LED.?
LED.CapsLock ---> LED.?
LED.ScrollLock ---> LED.?
```

Interface `0003:17EF:609B.008B`:

```
05 0c 09 01 a1 01 85 01 19 00 2a 3c 02 15 00 26 3c 02 95 01 75 10 81 00 05 01 0a 68 01 15 80 25 7f 95 01 75 08 81 02 c0 05 01 09 80 a1 01 85 02 19 81 29 83 15 00 25 01 75 01 95 03 81 02 95 05 81 01 05 01 0a 68 01 15 80 25 7f 95 01 75 08 81 02 c0 06 01 ff 09 01 a1 01 85 05 95 07 75 08 15 00 26 ff 00 09 20 b1 03 c0 

  INPUT(1)[INPUT]
    Field(0)
      Application(Consumer.0001)
      Usage(573)
        Consumer.0000
        Consumer.0001
        Consumer.0002
        Consumer.0003
        Consumer.0004
        ... Consumer sequence left out
        Consumer.0235
        Consumer.0236
        Consumer.0237
        Consumer.HorizontalWheel
        Consumer.0239
        Consumer.023a
        Consumer.023b
        Consumer.023c
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(572)
      Report Size(16)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Array Absolute )
    Field(1)
      Application(Consumer.0001)
      Usage(1)
        GenericDesktop.0168
      Logical Minimum(-128)
      Logical Maximum(127)
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(16)
      Flags( Variable Absolute )
  INPUT(2)[INPUT]
    Field(0)
      Application(GenericDesktop.SystemControl)
      Usage(3)
        GenericDesktop.SystemPowerDown
        GenericDesktop.SystemSleep
        GenericDesktop.SystemWakeUp
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(1)
      Report Size(1)
      Report Count(3)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Variable Absolute )
    Field(1)
      Application(GenericDesktop.SystemControl)
      Usage(1)
        GenericDesktop.0168
      Logical Minimum(-128)
      Logical Maximum(127)
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(8)
      Flags( Variable Absolute )
  FEATURE(5)[FEATURE]
    Field(0)
      Application(ff01.0001)
      Usage(7)
        ff01.0020
        ff01.0020
        ff01.0020
        ff01.0020
        ff01.0020
        ff01.0020
        ff01.0020
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(255)
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(7)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Constant Variable Absolute )

Consumer.0000 ---> Sync.Report
Consumer.0001 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0002 ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.002e ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.002f ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0030 ---> Key.Power
Consumer.0031 ---> Key.Restart
Consumer.0032 ---> Key.Sleep
Consumer.0033 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0034 ---> Key.Sleep
Consumer.0035 ---> Key.KbdIlluminationToggle
Consumer.0036 ---> Key.Btn0
Consumer.0037 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0038 ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.003e ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.003f ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0040 ---> Key.Menu
Consumer.0041 ---> Key.Select
Consumer.0042 ---> Key.Up
Consumer.0043 ---> Key.Down
Consumer.0044 ---> Key.Left
Consumer.0045 ---> Key.Right
Consumer.0046 ---> Key.Esc
Consumer.0047 ---> Key.KPPlus
Consumer.0048 ---> Key.KPMinus
Consumer.0049 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.004a ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.005e ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.005f ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0060 ---> Key.Info
Consumer.0061 ---> Key.Subtitle
Consumer.0062 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0063 ---> Key.VCR
Consumer.0064 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0065 ---> Key.Camera
Consumer.0066 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0067 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0068 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0069 ---> Key.Red
Consumer.006a ---> Key.Green
Consumer.006b ---> Key.Blue
Consumer.006c ---> Key.Yellow
Consumer.006d ---> Key.Zoom
Consumer.006e ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.006f ---> Key.BrightnessUp
Consumer.0070 ---> Key.BrightnessDown
Consumer.0071 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0072 ---> Key.?
Consumer.0073 ---> Key.BrightnessMin
Consumer.0074 ---> Key.BrightnessMax
Consumer.0075 ---> Key.BrightnessAuto
Consumer.0076 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0077 ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.0080 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0081 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0082 ---> Key.?
Consumer.0083 ---> Key.Last
Consumer.0084 ---> Key.Enter
Consumer.0085 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0086 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0087 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0088 ---> Key.PC
Consumer.0089 ---> Key.TV
Consumer.008a ---> Key.WWW
Consumer.008b ---> Key.DVD
Consumer.008c ---> Key.Phone
Consumer.008d ---> Key.Program
Consumer.008e ---> Key.?
Consumer.008f ---> Key.?
Consumer.0090 ---> Key.Memo
Consumer.0091 ---> Key.CD
Consumer.0092 ---> Key.VCR
Consumer.0093 ---> Key.Tuner
Consumer.0094 ---> Key.Exit
Consumer.0095 ---> Key.Help
Consumer.0096 ---> Key.Tape
Consumer.0097 ---> Key.TV2
Consumer.0098 ---> Key.Sat
Consumer.0099 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.009a ---> Key.PVR
Consumer.009b ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.009c ---> Key.ChannelUp
Consumer.009d ---> Key.ChannelDown
Consumer.009e ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.009f ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00a0 ---> Key.VCR2
Consumer.00a1 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00a2 ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.00ae ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00af ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00b0 ---> Key.Play
Consumer.00b1 ---> Key.Pause
Consumer.00b2 ---> Key.Record
Consumer.00b3 ---> Key.FastForward
Consumer.00b4 ---> Key.Rewind
Consumer.00b5 ---> Key.NextSong
Consumer.00b6 ---> Key.PreviousSong
Consumer.00b7 ---> Key.StopCD
Consumer.00b8 ---> Key.EjectCD
Consumer.00b9 ---> Key.Shuffle
Consumer.00ba ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00bb ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00bc ---> Key.?
Consumer.00bd ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00be ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00bf ---> Key.Slow
Consumer.00c0 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00c1 ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.00cb ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00cc ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00cd ---> Key.PlayPause
Consumer.00ce ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00cf ---> Key.VoiceCommand
Consumer.00d0 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00d1 ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.00de ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00df ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00e0 ---> Absolute.Volume
Consumer.00e1 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00e2 ---> Key.Mute
Consumer.00e3 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00e4 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00e5 ---> Key.BassBoost
Consumer.00e6 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00e7 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00e8 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00e9 ---> Key.VolumeUp
Consumer.00ea ---> Key.VolumeDown
Consumer.00eb ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00ec ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.00f3 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00f4 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00f5 ---> Key.Slow
Consumer.00f6 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.00f7 ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.017f ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0180 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0181 ---> Key.ButtonConfig
Consumer.0182 ---> Key.Bookmarks
Consumer.0183 ---> Key.Config
Consumer.0184 ---> Key.?
Consumer.0185 ---> Key.?
Consumer.0186 ---> Key.?
Consumer.0187 ---> Key.?
Consumer.0188 ---> Key.?
Consumer.0189 ---> Key.?
Consumer.018a ---> Key.Mail
Consumer.018b ---> Key.?
Consumer.018c ---> Key.?
Consumer.018d ---> Key.?
Consumer.018e ---> Key.Calendar
Consumer.018f ---> Key.TaskManager
Consumer.0190 ---> Key.Journal
Consumer.0191 ---> Key.Finance
Consumer.0192 ---> Key.Calc
Consumer.0193 ---> Key.Player
Consumer.0194 ---> Key.File
Consumer.0195 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0196 ---> Key.WWW
Consumer.0197 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0198 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0199 ---> Key.Chat
Consumer.019a ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.019b ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.019c ---> Key.Logoff
Consumer.019d ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.019e ---> Key.Coffee
Consumer.019f ---> Key.ControlPanel
Consumer.01a0 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01a1 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01a2 ---> Key.AppSelect
Consumer.01a3 ---> Key.Next
Consumer.01a4 ---> Key.Previous
Consumer.01a5 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01a6 ---> Key.Help
Consumer.01a7 ---> Key.Documents
Consumer.01a8 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01a9 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01aa ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01ab ---> Key.SpellCheck
Consumer.01ac ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01ad ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01ae ---> Key.Keyboard
Consumer.01af ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01b0 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01b1 ---> Key.ScreenSaver
Consumer.01b2 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01b3 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01b4 ---> Key.File
Consumer.01b5 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01b6 ---> Key.?
Consumer.01b7 ---> Key.Audio
Consumer.01b8 ---> Key.Video
Consumer.01b9 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01ba ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01bb ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01bc ---> Key.?
Consumer.01bd ---> Key.Info
Consumer.01be ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.01bf ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.01ff ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0200 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0201 ---> Key.New
Consumer.0202 ---> Key.Open
Consumer.0203 ---> Key.Close
Consumer.0204 ---> Key.Exit
Consumer.0205 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0206 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0207 ---> Key.Save
Consumer.0208 ---> Key.Print
Consumer.0209 ---> Key.Props
Consumer.020a ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.020b ---> Key.Unknown
... Key.Unknown lines left out
Consumer.0218 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0219 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.021a ---> Key.Undo
Consumer.021b ---> Key.Copy
Consumer.021c ---> Key.Cut
Consumer.021d ---> Key.Paste
Consumer.021e ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.021f ---> Key.Find
Consumer.0220 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0221 ---> Key.Search
Consumer.0222 ---> Key.Goto
Consumer.0223 ---> Key.HomePage
Consumer.0224 ---> Key.Back
Consumer.0225 ---> Key.Forward
Consumer.0226 ---> Key.Stop
Consumer.0227 ---> Key.Refresh
Consumer.0228 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0229 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.022a ---> Key.Bookmarks
Consumer.022b ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.022c ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.022d ---> Key.?
Consumer.022e ---> Key.?
Consumer.022f ---> Key.?
Consumer.0230 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0231 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0232 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0233 ---> Key.ScrollUp
Consumer.0234 ---> Key.ScrollDown
Consumer.0235 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0236 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.0237 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.HorizontalWheel ---> Relative.HWheel
Consumer.0239 ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.023a ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.023b ---> Key.Unknown
Consumer.023c ---> Key.Unknown
GenericDesktop.0168 ---> Absolute.Misc
GenericDesktop.SystemPowerDown ---> Key.Power
GenericDesktop.SystemSleep ---> Key.Sleep
GenericDesktop.SystemWakeUp ---> Key.WakeUp
GenericDesktop.0168 ---> Sync.Report
```

HID Descriptor of the old keyboard, interface `0003:17EF:6022.0087` (only one keyboard interface):

```
05 01 09 06 a1 01 05 07 19 e0 29 e7 15 00 25 01 75 01 95 08 81 02 95 01 75 08 81 01 15 00 26 a4 00 19 00 2a a4 00 05 07 75 08 95 06 81 00 c0 

  INPUT[INPUT]
    Field(0)
      Application(GenericDesktop.Keyboard)
      Usage(8)
        Keyboard.00e0
        Keyboard.00e1
        Keyboard.00e2
        Keyboard.00e3
        Keyboard.00e4
        Keyboard.00e5
        Keyboard.00e6
        Keyboard.00e7
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(1)
      Report Size(1)
      Report Count(8)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Variable Absolute )
    Field(1)
      Application(GenericDesktop.Keyboard)
      Usage(165)
        Keyboard.0000
        Keyboard.0001
        Keyboard.0002
        Keyboard.0003
        Keyboard.0004
        ... Keyboard sequence left out
        Keyboard.009f
        Keyboard.00a0
        Keyboard.00a1
        Keyboard.00a2
        Keyboard.00a3
        Keyboard.00a4
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(164)
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(6)
      Report Offset(16)
      Flags( Array Absolute )

Keyboard.00e0 ---> Key.LeftControl
Keyboard.00e1 ---> Key.LeftShift
Keyboard.00e2 ---> Key.LeftAlt
Keyboard.00e3 ---> Key.LeftMeta
Keyboard.00e4 ---> Key.RightCtrl
Keyboard.00e5 ---> Key.RightShift
Keyboard.00e6 ---> Key.RightAlt
Keyboard.00e7 ---> Key.RightMeta
Keyboard.0000 ---> Sync.Report
Keyboard.0001 ---> Sync.Report
Keyboard.0002 ---> Sync.Report
Keyboard.0003 ---> Sync.Report
Keyboard.0004 ---> Key.A
Keyboard.0005 ---> Key.B
Keyboard.0006 ---> Key.C
Keyboard.0007 ---> Key.D
Keyboard.0008 ---> Key.E
Keyboard.0009 ---> Key.F
Keyboard.000a ---> Key.G
Keyboard.000b ---> Key.H
Keyboard.000c ---> Key.I
Keyboard.000d ---> Key.J
Keyboard.000e ---> Key.K
Keyboard.000f ---> Key.L
Keyboard.0010 ---> Key.M
Keyboard.0011 ---> Key.N
Keyboard.0012 ---> Key.O
Keyboard.0013 ---> Key.P
Keyboard.0014 ---> Key.Q
Keyboard.0015 ---> Key.R
Keyboard.0016 ---> Key.S
Keyboard.0017 ---> Key.T
Keyboard.0018 ---> Key.U
Keyboard.0019 ---> Key.V
Keyboard.001a ---> Key.W
Keyboard.001b ---> Key.X
Keyboard.001c ---> Key.Y
Keyboard.001d ---> Key.Z
Keyboard.001e ---> Key.1
Keyboard.001f ---> Key.2
Keyboard.0020 ---> Key.3
Keyboard.0021 ---> Key.4
Keyboard.0022 ---> Key.5
Keyboard.0023 ---> Key.6
Keyboard.0024 ---> Key.7
Keyboard.0025 ---> Key.8
Keyboard.0026 ---> Key.9
Keyboard.0027 ---> Key.0
Keyboard.0028 ---> Key.Enter
Keyboard.0029 ---> Key.Esc
Keyboard.002a ---> Key.Backspace
Keyboard.002b ---> Key.Tab
Keyboard.002c ---> Key.Space
Keyboard.002d ---> Key.Minus
Keyboard.002e ---> Key.Equal
Keyboard.002f ---> Key.LeftBrace
Keyboard.0030 ---> Key.RightBrace
Keyboard.0031 ---> Key.BackSlash
Keyboard.0032 ---> Key.BackSlash
Keyboard.0033 ---> Key.Semicolon
Keyboard.0034 ---> Key.Apostrophe
Keyboard.0035 ---> Key.Grave
Keyboard.0036 ---> Key.Comma
Keyboard.0037 ---> Key.Dot
Keyboard.0038 ---> Key.Slash
Keyboard.0039 ---> Key.CapsLock
Keyboard.003a ---> Key.F1
Keyboard.003b ---> Key.F2
Keyboard.003c ---> Key.F3
Keyboard.003d ---> Key.F4
Keyboard.003e ---> Key.F5
Keyboard.003f ---> Key.F6
Keyboard.0040 ---> Key.F7
Keyboard.0041 ---> Key.F8
Keyboard.0042 ---> Key.F9
Keyboard.0043 ---> Key.F10
Keyboard.0044 ---> Key.F11
Keyboard.0045 ---> Key.F12
Keyboard.0046 ---> Key.SysRq
Keyboard.0047 ---> Key.ScrollLock
Keyboard.0048 ---> Key.Pause
Keyboard.0049 ---> Key.Insert
Keyboard.004a ---> Key.Home
Keyboard.004b ---> Key.PageUp
Keyboard.004c ---> Key.Delete
Keyboard.004d ---> Key.End
Keyboard.004e ---> Key.PageDown
Keyboard.004f ---> Key.Right
Keyboard.0050 ---> Key.Left
Keyboard.0051 ---> Key.Down
Keyboard.0052 ---> Key.Up
Keyboard.0053 ---> Key.NumLock
Keyboard.0054 ---> Key.KPSlash
Keyboard.0055 ---> Key.KPAsterisk
Keyboard.0056 ---> Key.KPMinus
Keyboard.0057 ---> Key.KPPlus
Keyboard.0058 ---> Key.KPEnter
Keyboard.0059 ---> Key.KP1
Keyboard.005a ---> Key.KP2
Keyboard.005b ---> Key.KP3
Keyboard.005c ---> Key.KP4
Keyboard.005d ---> Key.KP5
Keyboard.005e ---> Key.KP6
Keyboard.005f ---> Key.KP7
Keyboard.0060 ---> Key.KP8
Keyboard.0061 ---> Key.KP9
Keyboard.0062 ---> Key.KP0
Keyboard.0063 ---> Key.KPDot
Keyboard.0064 ---> Key.102nd
Keyboard.0065 ---> Key.Compose
Keyboard.0066 ---> Key.Power
Keyboard.0067 ---> Key.KPEqual
Keyboard.0068 ---> Key.F13
Keyboard.0069 ---> Key.F14
Keyboard.006a ---> Key.F15
Keyboard.006b ---> Key.F16
Keyboard.006c ---> Key.F17
Keyboard.006d ---> Key.F18
Keyboard.006e ---> Key.F19
Keyboard.006f ---> Key.F20
Keyboard.0070 ---> Key.F21
Keyboard.0071 ---> Key.F22
Keyboard.0072 ---> Key.F23
Keyboard.0073 ---> Key.F24
Keyboard.0074 ---> Key.Open
Keyboard.0075 ---> Key.Help
Keyboard.0076 ---> Key.Props
Keyboard.0077 ---> Key.Front
Keyboard.0078 ---> Key.Stop
Keyboard.0079 ---> Key.Again
Keyboard.007a ---> Key.Undo
Keyboard.007b ---> Key.Cut
Keyboard.007c ---> Key.Copy
Keyboard.007d ---> Key.Paste
Keyboard.007e ---> Key.Find
Keyboard.007f ---> Key.Mute
Keyboard.0080 ---> Key.VolumeUp
Keyboard.0081 ---> Key.VolumeDown
Keyboard.0082 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0083 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0084 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0085 ---> Key.KPComma
Keyboard.0086 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0087 ---> Key.RO
Keyboard.0088 ---> Key.Katakana/Hiragana
Keyboard.0089 ---> Key.Yen
Keyboard.008a ---> Key.Henkan
Keyboard.008b ---> Key.Muhenkan
Keyboard.008c ---> Key.KPJpComma
Keyboard.008d ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.008e ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.008f ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0090 ---> Key.Hangeul
Keyboard.0091 ---> Key.Hanja
Keyboard.0092 ---> Key.Katakana
Keyboard.0093 ---> Key.HIRAGANA
Keyboard.0094 ---> Key.Zenkaku/Hankaku
Keyboard.0095 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.0096 ---> Key.Unknown
    ... Key.Unknown lines left out
Keyboard.009a ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.009b ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.009c ---> Key.Delete
Keyboard.009d ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.009e ---> Key.Unknown
    ... Key.Unknown lines left out
Keyboard.00a3 ---> Key.Unknown
Keyboard.00a4 ---> Key.Unknown
```

---

(Issue experienced on [Lenovo Professional Wireless Keyboard](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/acc100313), an [ASUS keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904409/asus-primax-electronics-partially-working-on-ubunau-16-04-and-17-04)... both wireless keyboards manufactured by Primax.)

(Issue not experienced on Windows and GRUB.)

(Yves Trudeau has already played with it and implemented a [driver](https://github.com/y-trudeau/linux_lenovo_ultraslim_plus), but I would rather use something from vanilla kernel and something less hacky.)

Comment: This is just not how USB works.  Keyboards are not distinguished by what usage they send for the spacebar.  The 9th byte, and indeed all of the other bytes, are what the report descriptor says that they are.  You are expecting us to divine what the report descriptor is clairvoyantly.  A proper HID driver should be able to cope with reports of appropriate size, having read the report descriptor.  You do not even tell us which operating system this is; let alone what the supposed "issue" is or the USB device information.  And your Lenovo hyperlink is broken.

Comment: Hi @JdeBP, thanks for the comments. I have improved the answer.

Comment: Keyboards are not distinguished by spacebar codes, I only wanted to provide an example of the extra byte sent by the problematic keyboard. And an example of code sent by a working keyboard. I thought one random character is a fine to demonstrate the issue.
This class of 9-byte keyboards does not generically work on Linux – tested on multiple distributions and the newest kernels. On the other hand it works on Windows and even Grub. That is why I am looking for a proper HID driver.

Comment: If it's a HID keyboard, you can look at the HID descriptor via debugfs (`mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug`, `cat /sys/kernel/debug/hid/<dev>/rdesc`). This will describe the 9 bytes that are sent. The kernel understands HID keyboards natively, no need for extra drivers. The driver you linked sort of looks like it wants to process a usual HID report, but I don't have enough information. Have you tried connecting it without the special driver? What happens?

Comment: Thanks, @dirkt. Unfortunately I do not understand descriptors well enough to determine whether they are incorrect or whether Linux is mistransforming them (I suppose there should be more keys defined there). I added only those of the working keyboard (mouse `0003:17EF:609B.008A` on the same USB dongle left out).

Comment: Your problem is not that you get an extra data byte, your problem is that unless your keyboard is an LED tree with no alphanumeric keys, the HID descriptor is completely broken. The correct way to fix that is to add a quirk to the HID layer, not to write a completely new driver; your keyboard is not the only one with a broken descriptor.

Comment: Please add the following information to your question: (1) HID descriptor(s) of the old keyboard to compare. (2) Byte sequences of the following for both keyboards: press 'A', release 'A'. press 'S', release 'S'. press 'Shift', press 'A', release 'A', release 'Shift'. If there's any sort of slider, wheel or other analog input on the keyboard, jiggle that, too. (Proper images of this keyboard are astonishing difficult to google).

Comment: Thank you, @dirkt. There is no analog input on the keyboards. The new keyboard is depicted on this [page](https://www.lenovoquickpick.com/usa/accessorycategory/7/keyboards#accessory/67469).

Comment: Waiting for it to reopen so i can answer ...

Comment: Apparently it doesn't get enough votes to re-open. TL;DR: This looks like a bug in the kernel HID parser; the HID descriptor of 0003:17EF:609B.0089 is unusual, but valid IMO, but the kernel HID parser gets confused by it. The report format is pretty standard. Open a new question here and ping me with @dirkt if you want more details. Action: File a bug report with the kernel developers, probably the 'Input' maintainers (look around). The parser is in `drivers/hid/hid-core.c`, if you want to fix it yourself.

Comment: @JdeBP could you provide further comments on improving the question to have it reopened and let dirkt to answer it?

Comment: Many thanks, @dirkt, for all your effort. I tried to get the question reopened to avoid duplicates (to prevent a ban), but it got closed instead. It is very frustrating. No reason is provided. I opened a new question focused on the descriptor (so it is not a duplicate). You can find it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377830/linux-hid-driver-for-primax-wireless-keyboards